# How do I do an AcceptAsync of a socket with a timeout?

Tags: c#

Here is what I have now:

```
Socket myNewSocket = currentSocket.Accept();
```

Here is what I want:

```
Socket myNewSocket = AcceptWithTimeout(currentSocket, timeoutInMilliseconds)
```

Comment: Why would you need an AcceptAsync with timeout?

Comment: Chris, this is for doing Active mode FTP.  The problem I am having is the server connects properly then goes down when attempting to accept.  It just tries to accept forever.  Essentially due to a poor network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a `BeginAccept` and then have a timer that closes the socket to cancel the accept operation. Usually, though, servers just keep an asynchronous accept operation going constantly.